# How to send an object from a promise to a new rendered page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, promise, routes

1. I render my main page - here I have a list of units, if I press one unit I use an "onclick" function to load a generic page that is the same for all "units"
2. I pass the units-ID through this "onclick"-event, and go to an endpoint where I get JSON data with a promise for this specific unit (based on his ID).
3. I then want to render the generic page for this specific unit with all his specific data, but I do not understand how to send the units data to the newly rendered page, or, how do I send the units data to this page when it is rendered.

On the main html-page:

```
onclick="unitfunction({{ID}}"
```

Then in this function i have a promise that gets data from an endpoint:

```
(function () {
httpGet(url).then(function (result) {
        var unitdata = result;
        loadsite(unit-obj);
    });
})();
```

After the data is returned from the promise I execute the function to render the unit-site and want to send it data...

```
function loadsite(unit-obj) {
    window.location = './unitsite.html';
    document.getElementById("unit-name").innerHTML = unit-object.name;
       }
```

This does not work, because the unit-site has not been rendered, yet, so  the "getElementByID" I try to get does not exist (still on my main site when this function executes)

What methods can I use to solve this? For me, this is like: "Which came first, the chicken or the egg?"  :S

Comment: Data likely should be passed via URL. Depending on what kind of data it is, it can also be stored to cookies or local storage and retrieved from there.

Comment: Yes: But What I'm thinking is: I can load the unit-page on the "onclick"-function. then in the unit page, call a script that gets the unit-obj from that endpoint, but one problem then remains: How to pass the ID from "onclick"-function --> to the new opened html page, then get this ID into the function where i get the endpoint data.....?

Comment: This is exactly what the comment above is about.

Comment: So you mean like this:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage   ? So i can store it locally. Then render the new page, and have a script on the new page get the locally stored data for that item, right?

Comment: Yes. Or appending it to query string. It depends on whether an object should be 'sent' to any page or just this one.